# How can I center my search box in the middle of the div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span id="search_concept">Search by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#hcn">HCN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#casenote">Casenote</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which has the following effect:

[image: Search Box Not Centered!]

What I've been trying to do, and failing at, is centering this content so that the dropdown, textbox and button are all centre aligned and tight to each other.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: do you have additional classes / styles interfering as with normal bootstrap 3, they would completely fill the input group: https://www.bootply.com/oxBgrVy7b9

Comment: Also why use a fake drop down instead of a real one - surely if you need to pass that variable to a form, it needs to be an input rather than a ul

Comment: I'm using your code and the input-group is centered on my page with no additional CSS

Comment: You guys are correct, there was additional css: '/*input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}*/'

Comment: this run fine in this  jsfiddle link [https://jsfiddle.net/sugoel/jbnq806p/1/ ]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the`.input-group` class CSS with the following CSS.

```
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: "row",
  justify-content: "center",
  align-items: "center"
}
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding :)